# Using an r variable in a parameter that expects a function

Tags: r, function, variables, phyloseq

I have a loop through column names which returns a variable character. I would like to use the variable in a parameter that expects a function.

**Not Working**

```
i = "Cooling"
temp = phyloseq_to_deseq2(p2, ~i)}
```

**Works**

```
temp = phyloseq_to_deseq2(p2, ~Cooling)
```

**Not Working**

```
temp = phyloseq_to_deseq2(p2, ~"Cooling")}
```

The question below highlights the problem the str reference is not the r object in the function. Phyloseq_to_deseq2 requires the phyloseq package. How can I use a variable in a function that expects a function in a parameter?

[R: specifying variable name in function parameter for a function of general (universal) use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121542/r-specifying-variable-name-in-function-parameter-for-a-function-of-general-uni)

Comment: You can probably also just convert a character like `"~Cooling"` to a formula with `as.formula`.

Comment: @akrun and joran both are excellent ideas, thank you, however, this issue is not solved by either and even a combination of the two. akrun can you explain the purpose of the exclamation points?

Comment: I don't have that package, but it won't work if it is not \tidyverse compatible

Comment: @joran your solution worked with some fiddling! Thank you! You should answer the question with the as.formula solution for future users

Comment: @akrun, I do not think the package is tidyverse compatible (silly bioinformaticians) that would have may my foray into to this much easier. A phyloseq object is basically three tables connected by identifiers. Thank for the solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @joran in the comments. Using the function as.formula on a string containing the ~ passed the function as a parameter.

```
my_formula = as.formula("~Cooling")
temp = phyloseq_to_deseq2(p2, my_formula}
```